# LIMIT in SQL query giving error of incorrect syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

```
SELECT Name
    , Color, ProductID
FROM AdventureWorks2008R2.Production.Product
LIMIT 1;
```

When I'm running this query on my MS SQL Server 2012 it is giving this error:

```
Incorrect syntax near '1'.
```

I don't want to use `TOP`, only want to use `LIMIT` to show first row only.

Comment: `LIMIT` doesn't exist in SQL Server. It uses `TOP`. (`LIMIT` here would be seen as the alias for the object `Product`).

Comment: More info here: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp

Answer (score 1):

You are using sql server
its not limit but top

```
SELECT top 1 Name
    , Color, ProductID
FROM AdventureWorks2008R2.Production.Product
;
```